# How to group data in kdb+ using customized groups?

Tags: grouping, kdb

I have a table (`allsales`) with a column for time (`sale_time`). I want to group the data by `sale_time`. But I want to be able to bucket this. ex any data where time is between `00:00:00-03:00:00` should be grouped together, `03:00:00-06:00:00` should be grouped together and so on. Is there a way to write such a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xbar is useful for rounding to interval values e.g.

```
q)5 xbar 1 3 5 8 10 11 12 14 18
0 0 5 5 10 10 10 10 15
```

We can then use this to group rows into time groups, for your example:

```
q)s:([] t:13:00t+00:15t*til 24; v:til 24)

q)s
t            v
--------------
13:00:00.000 0
13:15:00.000 1
13:30:00.000 2
13:45:00.000 3
14:00:00.000 4
14:15:00.000 5
..

q)select count i,sum v by xbar[`int$03:00t;t] from s
t           | x  v
------------| ------
12:00:00.000| 8  28
15:00:00.000| 12 162
18:00:00.000| 4  86
```

"by xbar[`int$03:00t;t]" rounds the time column t to the nearest three hour value, then this is used as the group by.

Answer (score 0):

There are few more ways to achieve the same results.

```
q)select count i , sum v by t:01:00u*3 xbar t.hh  from s
q)select count i , sum v by t:180 xbar t.minute  from s
t    | x  v
-----| ------
12:00| 8  28
15:00| 12 162
18:00| 4  86
```

But in all cases, be careful of the `date` column if present in the table, otherwise same time window across different dates will generate the wrong results.

```
q)s:([] d:24#2013.05.07 2013.05.08;   t:13:00t+00:15t*til 24; v:til 24)
q)select count i , sum v by d, t:180 xbar t.minute  from s
d          t    | x v
----------------| ----
2013.05.07 12:00| 4 12
2013.05.07 15:00| 6 78
2013.05.07 18:00| 2 42
2013.05.08 12:00| 4 16
2013.05.08 15:00| 6 84
2013.05.08 18:00| 2 44
```